# How to create chart in QML with series data exposed from c++

Tags: c++, qml, qtcharts

I am filling `QLineSeries` data on c++ side and QML chart is supposed to consume them (and update as they change). Data producer is connected to `newData` which are added to the series data, and that should trigger repaint of the chart.

Previously, the `LineSeries` were manipulated in QML but now I don't know how to make the c++ `QLineSeries` instances accessible to QML.

```
// ...
#include<QtCharts/QLineSeries>
using namespace QtCharts;

/* class holding all data to be displayed as properties */
class UiData: public QObject{
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY(QLineSeries *xy READ getXy NOTIFY xyChanged);
   QLineSeries* getXy(){return &xy; }
   signals:
      void xyChanged();
   public slots:
      void newData(float x, float y){
         xy.append(x,y);
         emit xyChanged();
      }
   private:
      QLineSeries xy;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   QApplication app(argc,argv);
   QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
   UiData uiData;
   /* make the instance accessiblt from QML */
   engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("uiData",&uiData);
   engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
   // ...
   return qApp->exec();
}
```

main.qml:

```
ChartView{
   ValueAxis{
      id: _axisX;
   }
   ValueAxis{
      id: _axisY;
   }
   /*
   BEFORE:
   data in QML: easy, plus had JS slot calling _xySeries.append(...)
   */
   LineSeries{
      id: _xySeries;
      axisX: _axisX;
      axisY: _axisY;
   }

   /*
   NOW:
   how to use an already existing LineSeries instance (uiData.xy),
   and only change a few attributes, like axisX and axisY?

   Something like this:

   LineSeries(uiData.xy) {
      axisX: _axisX;
      axisY: _axisY;
   }

   or like this:

   component.onCompleted:{
      // where is something like ChartView.addSeries?
      // (there is ChartView.removeSeries already)
      uiData.xy.axisX=_axisX;                    
      uiData.xy.axisY=_axisY;
      addSeries(uiData.xy);
   }
   */
};
```

Is there a good solution to this?

In an extreme case, I can also create the whole ChartView in c++ (but then again, how to insert it into the QML?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be said that `LineSeries` is a `QLineSeries` + other functionalities, so `ChartView` uses those other functionalities.

What you must do is access the `LineSeries` in `UiData`, for this you must use the memory position.

```
class UiData: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QLineSeries* xy READ xy WRITE setXy NOTIFY xyChanged)
public:
    ...
    QLineSeries *xy() const
    {
        return mXy;
    }
    void setXy(QLineSeries *xy)
    {
        if(mXy == xy) return;
        if(mXy)
            if(mXy->parent() == this) // is owner
                delete mXy;
        mXy = xy;
        emit xyChanged();
    }
public slots:
    void newData(qreal x, qreal y){
        if(mXy){
            mXy->append(x, y);
        }
    }
    ...
signals:
    void xyChanged();
    ...
private:
    QLineSeries *mXy;
};
```

***.qml**

```
ChartView{
    ValueAxis{
        id: _axisX;
    }
    ValueAxis{
        id: _axisY;
    }
    LineSeries{
        id: _xySeries;
        axisX: _axisX;
        axisY: _axisY;
    }
}
Component.onCompleted: uiData.xy = _xySeries // <----
```

As you can see, a `QLineSeries` is not being created in C ++, but the pointer serves only to reference `LineSeries`.

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/51793635).

Comment: Alright, I understand. BY analogy, it is like boost::python-wrapped object, c++ object plus some extra info (like refcounting and stuff) but unlike in boost::python, the object must be created on the scripting site. I appreciate a lot your detailed anwer. I find myself using a few macros for all the setters etc, but it works nicely.